# Make a GET request to localhost in Unity C# script

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, get

I'm trying to make a GET request for a JSON payload from localhost in a Unity C# script. I've made successful POST, PUT, and GET requests with a separate C# file, but unity requires use of UnityWebRequest(s). My Unity code returns an error of "Unknown Error" in the Unity console, but in the log files the first error is cannot connect to destination host".

Similar questions were resolved by changing the web address. I know that my web address is correct, as I can make successful requests with the Postman application and my own separate C# code.
The debug code returns True for isNetworkError.

I set up my server using the ToDo API tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) and modified the item contents to just contain the ID and string data.

If somebody could tell me why it doesn't work, and provide a solution, I'd be very grateful!

My code:

```
    IEnumerator GetText()
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://...localhost:[my port]/api/Todo"))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(www.error);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(www.isNetworkError);
        }
        else
        {
            // Show results as text
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the format of the data on the web server:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "data": "String text"
  }
]
```

For reference, here is part of the working C# code that works separately to do the same thing:

```
async static void GetRequest(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check what version of .net framework you have for this project, also if you try 127.0.0.1 or ping the url from command line, will it resolves ok?

Comment: Hi Jerry, the version of .net I'm using is 4.7. I can put the url into my browser (https://localhost:44327/api/Todo/), it works perfectly too, displaying the text {"id":2,"data":"blah bla"}. I have successfully pinged both 127.0.0.1 and my public IP address, if that's of any help.

Comment: Were you ever able to get an answer for this?

Comment: @Robert I didn't unfortunately, I was just using Unity for a demo and so didn't pursue it further. Antoine just made a new comment though which might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

actually UnityWebRequest connects automatically on port 443 which is why it works with postman and not in unity

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to access **http://...localhost:[my port]/api/Todo** which is not a valid address I think. Please change it to the correct address.

Comment: Thanks, but this requires the same reply as the other comment. I wrote the address that way to keep it generic for readability on the forum. What I actually have in my code is: "https://localhost:44327/api/Todo/2", which works with Postman and my separate c# script.

Comment: Will the destination redirect the location with 301/302? as I know early verion of Unity cannot handle this.

Comment: It doesn't seem to, but thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score -1):

As your error states "cannot connect to destination host". This is likely because, "...localhost" is not a valid host.

Try changing "...localhost" to "localhost" and replace [my port] with a valid port number.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote it that way to keep it generic for readability on the forum. What I actually have in my code is: "https://localhost:44327/api/Todo/2", which works with Postman and my separate c# script.